# We need some functionality to be done using solspace Favorites

Tags: solspace

We don't found below thing's. Please let me know weather this think are possible

1) Does we can add single file from grid in favorite?

2) We need collection date of particular user. can it be possible?

3) Can we delete more than one favorite from list at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you cannot favorite a Grid field column. You can only favorite *channel entries* or *members* at this time.
2. Each favorited entries/members has a timestamp for when it was favorited, but there is no timestamp for the actual collection itself. However, if you're looking for the date when an entry/member was favorited *in a collection*, that is possible to look for (using `{exp:favorites:info}` or `{exp:favorites:entries}`/`{exp:favorites:members}`, for example)
3. The `{exp:favorites:delete_all}` tag might be useful in this case: http://www.solspace.com/docs/favorites/delete_all/

Comment: Point - 3) Yes we can delete by collection name but we need selected entry to be deleted at a time not one by one

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to delete ALL favorites for a particular entry? Sorry, that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Answer (score 0):

I also having the same problem so we change plan grid to relationship of that field.

But also that time having some problem need submit more then one entries submit at same time in sol space favorite.

I mean to say adding multiple entries at a time in favorite list.

Any one having any suggestion for that so please let us know.